# Only the first task executes when using "foreach" loop in R

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I am experimenting with foreach in R. However, I find that only the last instruction in the foreach loop is executed.

How do I get both instructions executed. Here is a piece of my very simple code below.

```
foreach (i=1:10) %dopar% {
  
  paste("Jimmy")
  paste("bobby")

}
```

The results are as below;

```
[[1]]
[1] "bobby"

[[2]]
[1] "bobby"

[[3]]
[1] "bobby"

[[4]]
[1] "bobby"

.....
```

I would have expected the results to contain both "Jimmy" & "Bobby"...how do I make it as such?

Comment: `c("Jimmy", "Bobby")`?

Comment: Thanks Flimzy. But as I had stated earlier, my real problem is how to get both the instructions to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `%>%` from `magrittr` package

```
foreach(i=1:3) %dopar%{
  paste("Jimmy") %>%
  paste("bobby")
}

#[[1]]
#[1] "Jimmy bobby"

#[[2]]
#[1] "Jimmy bobby"

#[[3]]
#[1] "Jimmy bobby"
```

Another example:

```
foreach(i=1:3, .combine=c) %dopar%{
sample(1:10, 1) %>% 
print %>% 
sqrt
}
#[1] 3
#[1] 4
#[1] 6
#[1] 1.732051 2.000000 2.449490
```